# What does adjoint of a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been studying Linear Algebra from Axler, and I came across adjoint of a linear map. I understood the properties and concept of adjoint, basically $\langle Tv,w \rangle = \langle v,T^*w \rangle $.

My question is why did we construct Adjoint? Why do we need this concept? All theorems like spectral theorem are defined on the basis of this concept, my question is why Adjoint, why not something arbitary like Transpose of Adjoint, you can get the drift?

Comment: I assume your confusion comes from when the underlying scalar field is complex, not real. In a nutshell, if you did not use the Hermitian adjoint, you would not be able to derive a lot of the nice properties that we care about. In other words, it is studied because it is desirable.

Comment: It is useful in order to *define* self-adjoint and/or normal operators that are important in physics and elsewhere. (You cannot speak about self-adjointness without a scalar product or without a fixed basis)

Comment: I get your idea, however i am not able to intitutively link it with some elementary concept, like complex numbers are a generalisation of real numbers and are needed to study root of -1, so how does adjoint come into picture, that is what is the elementary concept that motivated this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843109/motivation-of-adjoints-and-normal-operators