# Motivation of Adjoint Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Linear Algebra Done Right introduces the concept of Adjoint transfomations as

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. The adjoint of T is the function
>   $T^{*} : W \rightarrow V$ such that:
>
> $\langle T v, w\rangle=\left\langle v, T^{*} w\right\rangle$
>
> for every $v \in V$ and $w \in W$

But this is introduced without any motivation. We work through some examples and find $T^*$ and I think it is interesting it exists. But other than being neat what is the motivation to introduce such a concept? What does the above definition say about $V,W$ or $T$? Why do we need this concept? I can't find a good motivation else where as well.

Comment: The motivation for the adjoint might be clearer if the adjoint were instead defined as a linear map of the dual space $W^*$, but I don’t believe Axler has introduced that concept yet.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843109/motivation-of-adjoints-and-normal-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without reference to any euclidean structure, for any vector space $V$ you have a "duality bracket" $\langle , \rangle : V\times V^*\to K$ defined by $\langle v, f\rangle = f(v)$.

Of course when you have a linear form $f:W\to K$ and a linear map $T:V\to W$ you also get the composite $f\circ T : V\to K$ so you have $T^* : W^* \to V^*$, $T^*f := f\circ T$.

This satisfies the following equation $\langle T(v), f\rangle = f(T(V)) = T^*(f)(v) = \langle v, T^*(f)\rangle$.

This is very natural, all I've used is composition of maps and evaluation of maps on things : it feels motivated, and I don't know how your book does it, but there's a very interesting theory of duality between $V$ and $V^*$ so this duality bracket and this $T^*$ are natural, motivated objects.

Now when you have a scalar product $\langle, \rangle$ on each vector space $V,W$, the thing is that you have a canonical identification (under certain hypotheses : finite dimensionality or completeness) $V\to V^*$ that sends of course $w\mapsto \langle -, w\rangle$ and under this identification, the duality bracket mentioned above coincides with the scalar product (if $f=\langle -,w\rangle$, then $\langle v, f\rangle = f(v) = \langle v, w\rangle$).

So with this in mind, a natural question is : ok I know what the duality bracket becomes, what does $T^*$ become ? Of course now $T^* : W^* \to V^*$ becomes $W\to V$ with our identifications and we just have to determine what $T^*$ does on vectors. But vectors are determined by their scalar product on other vectors so to find what $T^*w$ is we just have to test against various $v$'s, in other words we need to know what $\langle v, T^*w\rangle$ is . But we have identified what the duality bracket is, and we know $T^*$ on linear forms, so with all our identifications, we *should* have $\langle v, T^*w\rangle = \langle Tv,w\rangle$.

Now it turns out that we can prove that there is such a $T^*w$ (under certain hypotheses like finite dimensionality or completeness), and so this desired equality becomes the definition of $T^*$.

So $T^*$ is just what it needs to be in order to complete the identification "$V\approx V^*$" in this euclidean context, where we identify duality brackets with scalar products.

Comment: Actually, we have not done duality. Should I read up on that before?

Comment: Ah ! Well amd has also commented that it would be clearer with duality. I don't know if you should read up on that before, the book probably has some plans concerning that. The only other way I could "motivate" it would be with transpose matrices, but if I remember correctly the aim of the book is to not use matrices. So you should either read up on duality first or take it on faith that it will be motivated by duality later.

Comment: Actually, it was introduced as a skip-able advanced topic. Are adjoint operators important for advanced linear algebra or can I skip them too?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. They are very relevant in real or complex linear algebra : to give you an example, if an endomorphism on a finite dimensional real vector space is equal to its adjoint, then it is diagonalizable; and there are many decomposition theorems that relate to adjoints or self-adjoint endomorphisms. They are also extremeley relevant in the case of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (real or complex). In "general linear algebra" ( over other fields) they are less important because scalar products make no sense, so we replace them with other context-dependent forms.